# Visual C++/CLI (CLR) Null pointer

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, c++-cli, clr

I wan't to implement the following code - the check if the pointer is null or not null. If the pointer points to object, then do sth with that object, if not - skip that code block.

My code:

```
ref class EchoClient {
private:
    GameMatrix^ gameMatrix;
public:
    EchoClient(void);
    EchoClient(GameMatrix^);
    void do();
};

EchoClient::EchoClient(void)
{
    this->gameMatrix = NULL;
}

EchoClient::EchoClient(gameMatrix)
{
    this->gameMatrix = gameMatrix;
}

void EchoClient::do() {
    if(this->gameMatrix != NULL)
    {
        this->gameMatrix->redrawMatrix();
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from 'int' to 'GameMatrix ^' k:\visual studio 2010\Projects\EchoClient3WS\EchoClient3WS\EchoClient.cpp    106
```

Any solutions ???

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`nullptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, I just find out this myself. Looks like google don't wan't to suggest a qualified answer is first page (i found the solution only at 5-th results page)

Comment: @ozzWANTED: Third result when searching for 'CLR/C++ null pointer'

Comment: First result when searching for "C++/CLI null pointer".  @ozz: you need to mark a good post like this as the answer.  Having people look at this needlessly is wasting everybody's time.

Comment: @Hans Passant: When I searched after I posted this, this was the first result too. Amazing how quickly Google indexes!

Comment: Why do so many SO comments report what Google can do after one knows the ideal query? I always Google before asking a question here and it is often the case that a slight change I didn't think of makes a big difference in the results.

Comment: So many hours of debugging summed up in 7 beautiful characters.